# exporting DOCKER_HOST in .bashrc produces a different result to the same command in the terminal

Tags: docker, bash, boot2docker

Before I can use my `docker` container (using Boot2Docker on OSX) I always have to remember to enter

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://$(boot2docker ip 2>/dev/null):2375
```

in my terminal, and naturally I often forget this.

So I figured I'd just add that line to my `~/.bashrc` file but when I've done this and check the value of `DOCKER_HOST` it's `tcp://192.168.42.43:4243` instead of `tcp://192.168.42.43:2375`.

Breaking it down:

- `boot2docker ip` => "The VM's Host only interface IP address is: 192.168.59.103"
- `boot2docker ip 2` => "The VM's Host only interface IP address is: 192.168.59.103"
- `boot2docker ip 2>/dev/null` => "192.168.59.103" (okay I sort of get that but I have no idea how that works, and I have no idea where the `:4243` is coming from."

What's actually going on here and why is the port different?

Comment: FYI: `>` redirects `stdout` and `2>` redirects `stderr`.

Comment: Okay that's interesting to know. ta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something else is setting that environment variable for you. Why are you dumping `stderr` from that command to `/dev/null`. Is some extra info coming to `stderr`?

I would do

```
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://$(boot2docker ip 2>/dev/null):2375" ;
echo "Docker Host is set to ${DOCKER_HOST}"
```

For some debugging as it is set, then query the value at a later stage to see if something else is messing with it.

Comment: yes the `boot2docker ip` command is quite verbose, and produces ` "The VM's Host only interface IP address is: 192.168.59.103"` - It turns out my issue was I should have put the export command into `~/.bash_profile` not `~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 10):

If you want your DOCKER_HOST environment variable to be set automatically for every terminal you open, use the "boot2docker shellinit" command.  You can add this line to your .bash_profile to take care of business:

```
$(boot2docker shellinit)
```

Unfortunately, this will give you an annoying error message if your boot2docker VM is not running when you open the terminal ("error in run: VM "boot2docker-vm" is not running.") Put this in your .bash_profile instead to suppress the error message:

```
$(boot2docker shellinit 2>/dev/null)
```

More details [at Github](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker-cli/issues/179)

NOTE: if you're using Docker Machine instead to manage boot2docker, the equivalent command is

```
eval "$(docker-machine env MACHINE-NAME)"
```

where MACHINE-NAME is the name of your boot2docker machine.

Comment: +1, you can even simply use `$(boot2docker shellinit)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the boot2docker's socket command is more useful here, also we can simplify things a bit.

If you've not set this up before just run this in your terminal:

```
  echo export DOCKER_HOST=\`boot2docker socket 2\>/dev/null\` >> ~/.bashrc
```

If you've already been messing with this, just change your line in .bashrc to this:

```
  export DOCKER_HOST=`boot2docker socket 2>/dev/null`
```

Now to test it has worked open a new terminal and run `docker run hello-world`.